# Has this pattern in Pascal's triangle been already found?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, factorial, combinatorial-proofs

I found this pattern in Pascal's triangle and I was wondering if it has already been found before :

```
            1                                +(1*1⁰) =  1  = 0!
          1   1                           -(1*1¹)+(1*2¹) =  1  = 1!
        1   2   1                      +(1*1²)-(2*2²)+(1*3²) =  2  = 2!
      1   3   3   1                 -(1*1³)+(3*2³)-(3*3³)+(1*4³) =  6  = 3!
    1   4   6   4   1            +(1*1⁴)-(4*2⁴)+(6*3⁴)-(4*4⁴)+(1*5⁴) =  24  = 4!
  1   5   10  10  5   1       -(1*1⁵)+(5*2⁵)-(10*3⁵)+(10*4⁵)-(5*5⁵)+(1*6⁵) =  120 = 5!
1   6   15  20  15  6   1  +(1*1⁶)-(6*2⁶)+(15*3⁶)-(20*4⁶)+(15*5⁶)-(6*6⁶)+(1*7⁶) =  720 = 6!
```

Comment: That could be a corollary of the binomial-coefficient representation of Pascal's triangle

Comment: That would be $\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}(j+1)^n=n!$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, one might try a proof via induction

Comment: Interesting.....

Comment: @PeterMelech, Instead, I think it would be $\sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{n+j}\binom{n}{j}(j+1)^{n}=n!$

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Of course!

Comment: @Mustafa Abdullah By the way..Congratulations for finding that! Probably noone can tell for sure though if it has been found before.

Comment: @Mustafa Abdullah, Brilliant observation

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following

The conjecture proposed is as followed

$\sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{n+j}\binom{n}{j}(j+1)^{n}=n!$

Let $S=\sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{n+j}\binom{n}{j}(j+1)^{n}\tag 1$

Now After expanding $(1+j)^n=\sum_{t=0}^{n}\binom{n}{t}(j)^{t}$

The sum $(1)$ becomes

$S=\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(-1)^{n+j}\binom{n}{j}\cdot \sum_{t=0}^{n}\binom{n}{t}(j)^{t}]\tag 2$

$S=(-1)^{n}\sum_{t=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}\cdot\binom{n}{t}(j)^{t}]\tag 3$

$$=(-1)^{n}\sum_{t=0}^{n}\binom{n}{t}\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}\cdot (j)^{t}]\tag 4$$

Let $S_2(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}\cdot (j)^{t}]\tag 5$

Now

$S_2(t)=0$ $\forall$$t<n$, This can be Easily proved by differentiating expansion of $nx(1+x)^{n-1}$ again and again and multiply by $x$ On both sides every time you differentiate and finally putting $x=-1$ in obtained sum

Now $S_2(n)=\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}\cdot (j)^{n}]\tag 6$

Now the $S$ becomes

$$S=(-1)^{n}\binom{n}{n}\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}\cdot (j)^{n}]\tag 4$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(-1)^{n+j}\binom{n}{j}\cdot (j)^{n}]\tag 4$$

Now this Expression can be understood Using nice Combinatorial argument That is available on MSE by [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott) ;[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/436420/925076)

Here is what It states

> $$\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n+j}j^n\binom{n}j=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(n-k)^n\binom{n}{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(n-k)^n\binom{n}k\;.$$
> Now imagine that you have $n$ toys to distribute to $n$ children, and you want each child to get a toy; clearly you can distribute the toys in $n!$ different ways. On the other hand, you can consider the number of ‘bad’ distributions, in which some child gets no toy. For $k=1,\dots,n$, $\binom{n}k(n-k)^n$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ of the children to receive no toy and to distribute the $n$ toys to the other $n-k$ children. Of course some of the $n-k$ potentially lucky children may end up with no toy; that’s why you need an inclusion-exclusion argument. It tells you that there are
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}k(n-k)^n$$
> bad distributions, and since there are $n^n=(-1)^0\binom{n}n(n-0)^n$ distributions altogether, there must be
> $$n^n-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}k(n-k)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n-k)^n$$good ones.

Hence good ones$=n!=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n-k)^n$

Which proves the conjecture

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{n+j} {n\choose j} (j+1)^n
\\ = n! [z^n] (-1)^n
\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {n\choose j} \exp((j+1)z)
\\ = n! [z^n] (-1)^n
\exp(z) (1-\exp(z))^n
\\ = n! (-1)^n [z^n] \exp(z) ((-1)^n z^n + \cdots)
\\ = n! (-1)^{2n} = n!.$$

Comment: Note the (not widely known) notation:  $[z^n]\,P(z)$ means: the coefficient of $z^n$ in $P(z)$.

Comment: It is presented in section 5.4. of *Concrete Mathematics*.

Comment: @Marko Riedel This is true but GEdgar is right to say that it is not a widely known notation outside the combinatorics community, that an undergraduate student for example is very likely not to have seen.